# Bohr Mollerup theorem: Proving logarithmic convexity using the functional equation of the Gamma function

Tags: calculus

The Bohr-Mollerup theorem states that the gamma function is the only logarithmically convex function satisfying f(1)=1 and f(x+1)=xf(x).

To show that the function is logarithmically convex, we must prove that
$$\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\ln\left(\Gamma\left(x\right)\right)>0$$
for x$\ge$ 0.
Using the functional equation we can write this as
$$\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\ln\left(\left(x-1\right)\Gamma\left(x-1\right)\right)$$

Which, using logarithm properties, simplifies to
$$\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\ln\left(\Gamma\left(x-1\right)\right)>\frac{1}{\left(x-1\right)^{2}}$$
Therefore, as $\frac{1}{\left(x-1\right)^{2}}$ is strictly positive it implies that
$\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\ln\left(\Gamma\left(x\right)\right)$ is also positive.

Therefore, it seems to me that using just the functional equation we can prove that the gamma function is logarithmically convex. Why, then, does the Bohr-Mollerup theorem require the gamma function to satisfy all 3 properties above, instead of just f(1)=1 and f(x+1)=xf(x)? Or is the proof that I wrote above wrong for some reason?

Comment: You have shown that $\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\ln\left(\Gamma\left(x\right)\right)>0$ is equivalent to $\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\ln\left(\Gamma\left(x-1\right)\right)>\frac{1}{\left(x-1\right)^{2}}$, but that proves none of these inequalities.

Comment: Why can't we just say X=x+1 in $\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\ln\left(\Gamma\left(x-1\right)\right)>\frac{1}{\left(x-1\right)^{2}}$ to get $\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\ln\left(\Gamma\left(X\right)\right)>\frac{1}{\left(X\right)^{2}}>0$? @MartinR

Comment: You don't have $\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\ln\left(\Gamma\left(x-1\right)\right)>\frac{1}{\left(x-1\right)^{2}}$, because that inequality already assumes that the Gamma function is logarithmically convex.

Comment: @MartinR Right, I see, thanks for your response. But since we assumed that the first step is true, couldn't we use it as the base case in an inductive proof?